# Specify own Formatter in configuration file of java logger

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I wrote a `Formatter` (`test.MyFormatter`) by extending the class `java.util.logging.Formatter`;

Now I want to use `test.MyFormatter` instead of `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter`:

in the configuration file i replaced the entry:

`java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter`

with

`java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = test.MyFormatter`

unfortunately this is not working.

can somebody explain me, if what I am doing is:

1. correct
2. if yes, why it not working?

Comment: Define "not working".  Are you getting an exception? If so, what is it? Or is your Formatter ignored?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html) your configuration is correct.

If it is not working double check that

1. `test.MyFormatter` is in your class
   path
2. Check that you don't accidentally use Log4J or Commons-logging.
3. Check that your configuration is loaded.
4. Check that your `MyFormatter` has public constructor without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the default configuration using the  [LogManager](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) class. Something like this:

```
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(
      getClass().getResourceAsStream("path/to/logging.xml");
```